# K nearest neighbor in sklearn radius - ellipse

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

When I use `knn` algorithm in `sklearn`, I can get the nearest neighbors within a radius I specify i.e. it returns a circle shape of nearest neighbors within that radius. Is there an implementation where you can specify two radius values to return an ellipse shape of nearest neighbors?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a custom distance metric in [`NearestNeighbors`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors):

```
# aspect of the axis a, b of the ellipse
aspect = b / a
dist = lambda p0, p1: math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect)
nn = NearestNeighbors(radius=1.0, metric=dist)
```

Or directly [use the `KDTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kdtree-and-balltree-classes) with a [custom metric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])

# aspect of the axis a, b of the ellipse
aspect = b / a
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc', func = lambda p0, p1: math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect))
kdt = KDTree(X, leaf_size=30, metric=dist)

# now kdt allows queries with ellipses with aspect := b / a
kdt.query([0.1337, -0.42], k=6)
```

Of course you can choose to apply any affine transformation in your distance metric to get rotation and scaling for oriented ellipses.

Comment: Quick question: in the `kdt.query` where do can I specify `b` and `a`?

Comment: @Javiar you cannot, you have to build a new `NearestNeighbors` / `KDTree` if you're changing the aspect ratio of `a` and `b` / when you change the distance metric.

Comment: Hmm .. I need to see how I can modify your solution to fit my problem. But thanks for the useful pointer - I will upvote your answer.

Comment: I don't know if sklearn changed since this answer, but `TypeError: get_metric() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)`

Comment: @AaronBramson I fixed the syntax error: you have to use a keyword argument now

Comment: But now it throws: `ValueError: metric PyFuncDistance is not valid for KDTree`.  This is consistent with what I've read elsewhere.  You can use custom metrics for KNN, but not for KDTrees...I still hope it's possible though.  Having said that...it should be possible to achieve the same thing using the KNN radius parameters and a really high k.

Comment: @AaronBramson are you using dense or sparse arrays? According to the docs: *The classes in sklearn.neighbors can handle either NumPy arrays or scipy.sparse matrices as input. For dense matrices, **a large number of possible distance metrics** are supported. For sparse matrices, **arbitrary Minkowski metrics** are supported for searches.*